# Signed Graph from positive and negative correlations

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I want to create a signed graph where the edges of my graph are either green (for a positive correlation) or red (for a negative correlation). I only managed to create a graph from a thresholded adjacency matrix so far (greater than x), but struggling with this and didn't find a function in Mathematica. I'm also not sure if it's even possible  :/

Is it also possible to make the edge lines thicker for a stronger correlation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
n = 3;
corrMat = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}]; 
Graph[Flatten@Table[
      Style[DirectedEdge[i, j], If[corrMat[[i, j]] > 0, Green, Red], 
      Thickness[.001 Abs[corrMat[[i, j]]]]], {i, n}, {j, n}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Perhaps better:

```
Graph[Flatten@ MapIndexed[
      Style[DirectedEdge @@ #2, If[#1 > 0, Green, Red], Thickness[.001 Abs[#1]]] &, 
      corrMat, {2}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `WeightedAdjacencyGraph` and set the edge styles using `SetProperty`:

```
corrMat = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 4}]; 

wag = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[corrMat];
SetProperty[wag, EdgeStyle -> {x_ :> (PropertyValue[{wag, x}, EdgeWeight] /. 
  {_?Positive -> Green, _?Negative -> Red})}]
```

[image]

> *Is it also possible to make the edge lines thicker for a stronger correlation?*

```
SetProperty[wag, EdgeStyle -> {x_ :> (PropertyValue[{wag, x}, EdgeWeight] /. 
 {a_?Positive -> Directive[Thickness[Abs@a/40], Arrowheads[Max[.03, Abs@a/10]], 
    Opacity[.5], Green], 
  b_?Negative -> Directive[Thickness[Abs@b/40], Arrowheads[Max[.03, Abs@b/10]], 
    Opacity[.5], Red]})}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With IGraph/M, you could build and style the graph like this:

```
vecs = RandomReal[1, {10, 20}];
wam = Outer[Correlation, vecs, vecs, 1]; (* weighted adjacency matrix *)

MatrixPlot[wam]
```

[image]

```
<<IGraphM`

IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph[wam, GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding", Background -> Black] //
  IGEdgeMap[
    Directive[
      AbsoluteThickness[5 Abs[#]],
      ColorData[{"LightTemperatureMap", {-1, 1}}][#]
    ] &,
    EdgeStyle -> IGEdgeProp[EdgeWeight]
  ]
```

[image]